# After importing opencv-python , the corresponding functions don't work

Tags: opencv, imshow, imread, python-3.11

I'm new to learning on `opencv-python`.
So I started by creating a new python project named OpenCV and then imported `opencv-python` package and then started typing in my code in a new Python file. But once I try running the file I keep getting error.

[Code And Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ3l4.png)

It seems as if `imread()` and `imshow()` - none are accepted.
I tried importing `imread(`) separately by using `cmd` and my terminal but nothing seems to works.
It further shows legacy error.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg', 1)
print(img)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(10000)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mac/myprojects/opencv/read_and_display_image.py", line 1, in 
import cv2

File "/Users/mac/myprojects/opencv/openenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 181, in 
bootstrap()

File "/Users/mac/myprojects/opencv/openenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 153, in bootstrap
native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mac/myprojects/opencv/openenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _VTRegisterSupplementalVideoDecoderIfAvailable

Referenced from: /Users/mac/myprojects/opencv/openenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavcodec.59.37.100.dylib

Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Versions/A/VideoToolbox
in /Users/mac/myprojects/opencv/openenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavcodec.59.37.100.dylib

Comment: please share error and code snippets instead of their picture

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and also [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.